# Plotted function is spiky, how to make it render smoother

Tags: gnuplot

Every time there is a narrow peak in my function, gnuplot renders it as a spike:

[image: spiky, zoomed out]

And only after I zoom in, it can be seen that it's actually smooth:

[image: smooth, zoomed in]

Is there a way to force gnuplot into evaluating the function more frequently/densely, so that it renders it nicer and with better quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"is there a way to force gnuplot into evaluating the function more frequently/densely"

```
  set samples 1000   # or some other sufficiently large number
```